# How to make Windows 10 Bluetooth audio devices work more consistently = not stop partially working at "random" moments?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, wireless-headset, usb-headset

This has been a quite annoying issue for me for a while, but not necessarily worth fixing as it's not that common. The frustrating part is that it's "random" and can occur at the worst possible moment, e.g. before an important call.

Now it happens with Sennheiser Momentum M3 AEBT. I know it's device independent since it also happened on old laptop and 2x old BT headsets - Momentum M2 and Razer Hammerheads. The only things in common are Windows 10 and a bunch of apps, although it also was happening with nearly clean Windows install on this device. It looks to be not the greatest ever coding of Microsoft as I found similar complaints without any solutions all over the internet.

Basically, the devices, all of them, so:

- one for standard high quality BT connections - only for listening
- one for low quality output + input combo for BT
- one for standard high quality non-BT (USB cable) connection

can randomly and alternately without any sort of recognizable pattern:

- stop showing up in the system
- show up but output no sound
- output sound but stop after X seconds, whether by disconnection or just pausing, after reconnection the process repeats
- worst case scenario this can also lead to hung system (e.g. later when going to sleep) if I try to fix it with some (dis)connection/(un)pairing attempts, Windows Audio service restarts (which often don't complete) and turning off/on of BT devices. Often these actions help though.

Sometimes it happens more often, sometimes it's very rare. It might be partially related to (dis)connection of cable to charge the headset as issues tend to occur most likely after at least one charge. All goes always back to normal after a system restart,

I've tried also:

- looking in Windows event log - noticed nothing interesting there
- reinstalling BT drivers
- traditional `/sfc` etc. commands - they reported nothing interesting

to no avail.

I'm wondering if there's a known good way to deal with these issues. Perhaps some script to restart everything related to audio, but I'm not sure what there can be other than force restarting mentioned Windows Audio service and some chosen BT devices. Any clue if there's anything that could make it more consistent?

Comment: The only thing you can do with bluetooth issues, is to buy a bluetooth usb adapter and turn the other adapter off in device manager. 

Bluetooth is just faulty by design, and I personally despise it as it has no options to look into why stuff don't work.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas are you saying external adapters are more stable than regular ones? Well, BT itself isn't perfect for sure, but I don't have these kind of issues on Android or Linux, although I aven't tested comparably much on Linux.

Comment: What I have found is my own experience - An old laptop I recommissioned - a HP2560P every day would just disconnect my bluetooth devices - The only mouse I like to use regularly is a Microsoft Bluetooth one which I know works well, and has worked for years. Firstly I disabled the bluetooth in device manager then picked up a Bluetooth LE (low energy) USB adapter. I always use the Windows Bluetooth drivers so all I did was plug it in, and then pair all my devices to the new USB adapter. Never had any issues since, but that really is all you can do.

Comment: Unfortunately I have had less compatibility overall with linux - Mint didn't like my bluetooth at all, and ubuntu worked but had the most lengthy pairing process and sometimes just wasn't brought up on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth is one of the very few protocols that do not have any means of problem diagnosis. This makes it difficult to fix. I have found that if I first disable the internal bluetooth via device manager, then plugin a new USB Bluetooth LE (low energy) dongle & re-pair all BT devices, this fixes most issues.

It may be that an external USB device gets less radio interference than the internal, but there isn't any way that I can prove this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid it's not interference in my case though, as I'm using BT mouse daily with 0 issues, also at times a BT keyboard and that doesn't disconnect, disappear or stop working randomly either. It's more like something in the system is not right and bugs out the audio (and no other) devices internally, into non-controllable states.

Comment: Inteference is only one aspect - the bluetooth chipset and general makeup of the bluetooth stack are two others. 9/10 times this has solved the issues I find with bluetooth. Surely worth a try?